# Create a boolean matrix for matches in python matrix

Tags: python

Say I want to detect the zeros in `A`:

```
A = [1, 0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 5]
```

I figured

```
def check(x):
    if x!=0:
        return 0
    elif x==0:
        return 1
b = [check(x) for x in A]


-> b = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

But how to make this a oneliner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a list comprehension.  You can use the fact that 0 is falsey and any non-zero integer is truthy:

```
>>> A = [1, 0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 5]
>>> [0 if a else 1 for a in A]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Or, equivalently:

```
>>> [int(not a) for a in A]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Just a fun maths trick:

```
>>> [0**a for a in A]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> map((0).__pow__, A)
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 print map(lambda x: int(x==0), A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
A = [1, 0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 5]

result = [1 if i==0 else 0 for i in A]

>>> print result
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```